# Como puedo realizar la impresión en vertical con el print en python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

He tratado de sacar el salto de linea pero no me funciona. Este es el código que tengo en python 3.8:

```
def representacion(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        print("*",end="")
        i += 1
def histograma_horizontal(d):
    l1 = sorted(d.keys())
    n = len(l1)
    for i in l1:
        print("{0}:".format(i), end="")
        representacion(d[i])
        print("")

d1={"a":5,"b":10,"c":12,"d":11,"e":15,"f":20,"g":15,"h":9,"i":7,"j":2}
print(histograma_horizontal(d1))
```

Lo cual me imprime esto por pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es que se imprima de esta forma, ya trate sacando el salto de linea del "print" y no me funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si la pregunta es en python 3.8, no uses la etiqueta de 3.7

Comment: Listo lo voy a cambiar, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`print` no entiende de imprimir vertical o horizontal, solo manda una cadena a la salida estándar, con o sin saltos de línea.

Para imprimir el histograma verticalmente necesitas modificar el algoritmo, debes imprimir en cada iteración una fila, no una columna. Es decir, la primera línea será `"          *        \n"` y la última `"a b c d e f g h i j\n"`

Tienes dos enfoques posibles en principio.

### Generar las columnas como haces ahora pero transponer al imprimir

Un poco críptico, pero con un par de expresiones generadoras y `zip` puedes hacerlo de forma simple:

```
def histograma_vertical(d):
    max_n = max(d.values())
    print(*(" ".join(row)
            for row in zip(*(f"{' ' * (max_n - n)}{'*' * n}{key}"
                for key, n in sorted(d.items())))),
          sep="\n"
          )
```

La idea en el fondo es similar a tu implementación original:

- Generamos las columnas pero **invertidas** y **rellenando con espacios** lo que a cada una le falte para llegar al máximo (barra del histograma más alta).

  ```
  for key, n in sorted(d.items()):
      max_n = max(d.values())
      print(f"{' ' * (max_n - n)}{'*' * n}{key}")
  ```

  > ```
  >                ****a
  >               ******b
  >             ********c
  >          ***********d
  >       **************e
  >  *******************f
  >       **************g
  >             ********h
  >               ******i
  >                    *j
  > ```
- En vez de imprimir las lineas generadas, debemos imprimir el primer carácter de cada una, luego el segundo de cada una, etc. Ahí es dónde entra `zip`. Toma un número indeterminado de iterables (en nuestro caso las cadenas anteriores y en cada iteración genera una tupla con el i-ésimo item de cada iterable.)

  ```
  for c in zip("123", "abc"):
      print(c)
  ```

  > ```
  > ('1', 'a')
  > ('2', 'b')
  > ('3', 'c')
  > ```
- `str.join` simplemente se encarga de unir los caracteres de la tupla generada por `zip` y les añade un espacio en medio.

### Generar cada línea directamente

Otra implementación posible es ir generando las filas directamente en vez de generar las columnas y luego transponer:

```
def histograma_vertical(d):
    max_n = max(d.values())
    s_dict = sorted(d.items())
    for row in range(max_n + 1):
        print(*("*" if max_n - row < n else " " for key, n in s_dict))
    print(*d.keys())
```

En ambos casos la salida es:

```
d1 = {"a": 5, "b": 7, "c": 9, "d": 12, "e": 15, "f": 20, "g": 15, "h": 9, "i": 7, "j": 2}
histograma_vertical(d1)
```

> ```
>           *        
>           *        
>           *        
>           *        
>           *        
>         * * *      
>         * * *      
>         * * *      
>       * * * *      
>       * * * *      
>       * * * *      
>     * * * * * *    
>     * * * * * *    
>   * * * * * * * *  
>   * * * * * * * *  
> * * * * * * * * *  
> * * * * * * * * *  
> * * * * * * * * *  
> * * * * * * * * * *
> * * * * * * * * * *
> a b c d e f g h i j
> ```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió bastante soy nuevo en python y tengo una consulta el uso de las llaves en python como lo interpreta ?
Por ejemplo en este codigo
  for row in zip(*(f"{' ' * (max_n - n)}{'*' * n}{key}"

Comment: Son literales de cadena formateados (f-strings) disponibles en Python >= 3.6 las `{}`  se interpretan de forma similar a cómo hace `str.format`, el cual ya usas en tu código. Son dianas de reemplazo, el código que hay dentro es evaluado y su resultado convertido a cadena. Te dejo el enlace al PEP a partir del cual se implementaron: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/. En éste caso es equivalente a `"{}{}{}".format(' ' * (max_n - n),  "*"  *  n, key)` pero son muchísimo más eficientes en su implementación en C y sin pasar por la llamada al método.

Comment: Una ultima consulta estimado, la variable row como funciona o que valor toma ?
Por otro lado, gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: `row` es la tupla generada por cada iteración de `zip`, en la primera iteración es `(" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "*", " ", " ", " ", " ")` y la última `("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i")`, es decir, por cada iteración una tupla con los caracteres i-ésimos de cada una de las columnas. `zip` puede  parecer confuso hasta que se entiende, lo mejor es que pruebes a usarlo con varios iterables como en el ejemplo que doy en la pregunta y mires la salida.

Comment: Estimado, pero en el segundo ejemplo que me pusiste estas utilizando row sin necesidad de la función zip. Se podría decir que es una variable global?

Comment: No, `row` en ambos casos es la variable asociada al ciclo `for`, es decir toma en cada iteración el valor del item que toca del iterable iterado por el ciclo. En el primer caso las tuplas generadas por `zip()`, en el segundo los enteros generados por `range()`. Tal vez en el caso de `range` debería haber dado otro nombre para no confundir, por ejemplo: `for número_de_fila in range(max_n + 1):`. El ámbito de la variable depende el ámbito dónde se defina el `for` que la maneja, en este caso ambas son variables locales (definidas dentro de la función).

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero, saludos y gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Una última consulta FJSevilla el signo * porque lo puso en el print del primer y segundo ejemplo? no entiendo muy bien su uso para que sirve?

Comment: * en éste caso permite "desempaquetar" el generador. Hace falta porque vamos a imprimir los items de un iterable y debes pasar a print cada uno de ellos no el iterable, en el segundo caso solo tenemos una cadena. Quizás lo comprendas mejor con un ejemplo:  `print(["Hola", "mundo"])` y `print(*["Hola", "mundo"])`. El segundo caso es equivalente a : `print(["Hola", "mundo"][0], ["Hola", "mundo"][1])`  o lo que es lo mismo `print("Hola", "mundo")`.

Comment: He estado haciendo algunas modificaciones al código estimado y he visto que esta de más poner el join en esta parte del código print(*(" ".join("*" if max_n - row <= n else " ") for key, n in s_dict))
Poner antes del .join las comillas y espacio " ", porque ponerlo ?

Yo en base a lo que usted puso en sus ejemplos lo realice así
def histograma_vertical(d):
    l1 = sorted(d.keys())
    max_n = max(d.values())
    s_dict = sorted(d.items())
    for row in range(max_n + 1):
        print(*("*" if max_n - row < n else " " for key, n in s_dict))
    for i in l1:
        print(i,end=" ")

Comment: Si tiene razón, en la primera versión que hice no usé `*` para el desempaquetado, es decir: `print(" ".join(("*" if max_n - row <= n else " ") for key, n in s_dict))`, después decidí usarlo y se me pasó quietar el `join`... Buena observación. Edito.

Comment: Una consulta respecto a ello, porque no pone el espacio que pusiste delante del .join y tan solo reemplaza por el espacio en comillas " "? y también en el <=  debería ser <n nada más creo. Gracias por el apoyo estimado